# KnockoutJS: using "with" and document.getElementById

Tags: knockout.js, getelementbyid

Using `with` in KO causes elements to only render when the context of the data-bind is available. If I have script that runs on page-load and it's in charge of styling HTML elements, I get null if I call `document.getElementById` on an element whose data-bind uses `with`. Here's some pseudo code:

HTML:

```
<section data-bind="with: selectedView" id="sec">
    <span data-bind="text: title" id="span"></span>
</section>
```

JS that runs onload:

```
var PseudoViewModel = { ... };
ko.applyBindings(PseudoViewModel);

var x = document.getElementById("span"); // this is null
```

What's the best-practice for dynamically styling my elements? Thanks.

Comment: You are right; late night code. It should've been the span not the section. I've fixed the code. Sorry about that!

Comment: @ user: Ah, okay. Well, it doesn't really change my answer, but I've updated. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>What you're doing should work provided you're executing that code when the element exists ([example](http://jsbin.com/mosafoze/1)).</s>

In your example, `#sec` is the element with the `with` binding. `with` will omit *descendant* elements of `#sec` if the value of its `with` binding (`selectedView` in your example) is `null` or `undefined.` So `#sec` will always be there, just not the span within it. ([Example](http://jsbin.com/mosafoze/2)) *(Turns out that was an error in the code in the question, you meant to be targeting the `span`.)*

> What's the best-practice for dynamically styling my elements?

Best practice would be to use CSS, not JavaScript code, to style elements. Possibly in combination with the `css` binding, but not necessarily.

Another option is to do a custom binding which does the styling as part of the KO stuff. Custom bindings are very common in KO stuff. Since KO knows it's not rendering the element, it doesn't run the custom binding against it, and there's no error.

Or of course, if you do have elements that may or may not be present because you've used `with` or `if`, test they exist before using them:

```
var x = document.getElementById("span");
if (x) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

But again, recommendations in order:

1. Use CSS, not JavaScript, to style elements (possibly in conjunction with the `css` binding to apply a class to it); or
2. Use a custom binding if there has to be per-element code run (the great thing here is you define them once and reuse them); or
3. Use a guard (`if (x) { ... }`)

---

Here's an example of a custom binding that makes the element's color red if the value of the binding is more than 12 characters long, blue otherwise:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.colorByLength = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor/*, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext*/) {
        var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        element.style.color = (val && val.length > 12) ? "red" : "blue";
    }
};
```

Complete Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/jiyojeco/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Example Custom Binding</title>
</head>
<body>
<section data-bind="with: selectedView" id="sec">
    <span data-bind="text: title, colorByLength: title" id="span"></span>
</section>
<section data-bind="with: anotherView" id="sec">
    <span data-bind="text: title, colorByLength: title" id="span"></span>
</section>
<section data-bind="with: nullView" id="sec">
    <span data-bind="text: title, colorByLength: title" id="span"></span>
</section>
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use strict";

      // Custom binding
      ko.bindingHandlers.colorByLength = {
        update: function(element, valueAccessor/*, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext*/) {
          var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
          element.style.color = (val && val.length > 12) ? "red" : "blue";
        }
      };      

      var PseudoViewModel = {
        // This one will be red
        selectedView: {
          title: "This is the title"
        },

        // This one will be blue
        anotherView: {
          title: "Short title"
        },

        // And of course, this one isn't rendered at all
        nullView: null
      };
      ko.applyBindings(PseudoViewModel);

    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If indeed the desired behavior is for the element to not render when the data binding context isn't available, then you'll have to guard against that in your JavaScript:

```
function doThatThingOnPageLoad() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("sec");
  if (elem == null) return;

  continueDoingThatThingWith(elem);
}
```

Your JavaScript should just treat this element as optional, since it might just not be there.